# Zend Form element cannot be removed in Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: forms, zend-framework, frameworks, element

I needed to remove a zend form element, but the `removeElement($name)` function doesn't work.
My Form Class :

```
    class Forms_Signup extends Zend_Form
{   
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('signup');
        $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
        $id->addFilter('Int');
        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
        $name ->setLabel('Name : ')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                ->setValue('nametest');
        $password = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('password');
        $password->setLabel('Mot de Passe')
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StripTags')
                ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    }
}
```

In my controller action:

```
public function signupAction() {
    $signupForm = new Forms_Signup();
    $signupForm->removeElement('password');
    $this->view->signupform = $signupForm;
}
```

But the "password" form element still appears in my "signup.phtml" page.
I tried not to use `setRequired(true)` or other filters and validators but without result.

Comment: Your code looks okay. Are you outputting the form in the view just with `$this->signupForm`?

Comment: I found it, i used a DisplayGroup in my signup form : 

     $this->addDisplayGroup(
                array($name,$password), 'SignupData',array(
                                                       'legend' => 'Inscription'
                                                         )
                     );

so, i removed the form element from display group before removing it from the form and it works : 

    $signupForm->getDisplayGroup('SignupData')->removeElement('password');